# Limit the size of attachments in the Notes client?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Okay maybe iam getting blind or overlooking something.

Since you can set a size limit on the attachments in the Inotes client i thought you could do this for the Notes client as well.

Going through the server settings, policies and so on i came to the conclusion that it is not possible other than adding lotusscript to the querysave of the memo, appointment, (more) forms.

And iam not really a fan of that, it is a domino template, not a custom one. And i foresee some issues. Not that i can think of one right now.

And making a mail rule won't do either.

I could put the code in the onchange or validation event of the rich text elements. Again its the mail template.

So the big question is.....
Is there some way to do this with a policy or any other way than tampering with the mail template.

thx

--->The answer of ken made me realize my question was not complete.
to catch all the big mails we are planning to use the filesendr app an addon you can find them on openntf.
In our test env. it works like a charm. But people can still send large attachments, filesendr will kick in but in the senders his mailfile the memo with attachment will be stored, or in DAOS when installed.
We want to limit the size of the attachments allowed, without hacking the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing this on the client-side, you have two choices: modify the template, or write a plug-in that uses the C API Extension Manager feature to intercept NSFNoteUpdate operations and inspect the size of attachments.

Comment: rhsatrhs, thx for you reply. Again not the answer i was hoping for. But will look at the C Api.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a limit on the size of an attachment that gets added to a Notes email or document.  A user can attach a file of any size to a document, including an email document.  Perhaps using database quotas could limit that to a degree, but that's not the granularity you're looking for.

However, at the server you can set a limit on the maximum message size, and the Notes Router will fail a message if it is above that size (i.e. send a non-delivery report).  Follow these steps to find the setting:

- Go to the Domino Directory on the server,
- Click Configuration > Servers > Configurations.
- Select the configuration doc for your server.
- Click Router/SMTP > Restrictions and Controls > Restrictions
- Set the Maximum message size field to some value, say 10,000KBs

That will prevent any message larger than 10MBs from going through the router.

Comment: Ken, Thanks for the response, but not what i was hoping for. I should have added to the question that such a mailrule is not an option.  Although the memo won't be send the mail will be saved in the mailfile. For this we are planning to enroll the filesendr App of Declan Lynch, can be found on Openntf and the filesendr addon. Now i just need a way i can force users who wont to send attachments larger than les say 50 mb to use the filesendr app. I will update the question. Again thx.